# Matlab arrays operation

Tags: matlab

How to change an array of columns to an array of rows?

```
a=[1 ; 2 ;3]
```

then

```
a=[1 2 3]
```

Comment: Accepting answers is considered as good style on stackoverflow. Just click on the check mark belonging to the answer that answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

[Transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fixedpoint/ref/transpose.html).

```
>>a=[1;2;3]
>>a.'
>>ans =
 1     2     3
```

Edit: according to the documentation ...

> X' is the complex conjugate transpose
>   of X.
>
> X.' is the non-conjugate transpose.

Comment: Use with caution if used with complex numbers. A single quote is the the complex conjugate transpose. A dot followed by a single quote (.') only transposes.

Answer (score 2):

The operation you want is called a **matrix transposition**. The result is a matrix that turns all rows into columns and vice-versa. If your matrix is A, then the transposed result is acquired in B by:

```
B = A.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has many matrix routines. Use `transpose` operation.